# How to calculate number of rows without NA in a column in tidyverse

Tags: r, count, tidyverse

I have a DF with people by job, wage and other background statistics. One line is one person. I want to calculate number of people per job, average wage and number of people whith a wage. Some people have a missing wage "NA". I cant seem to calculate number of people with a wage without getting an error.

```
DF < DF %>%
   group_by(Job) %>%
   summarise(People = n(),
             Average_wage = mean(Wage, na.rm=T),
             People_with_a_wage = ???? )
```

I have tried the following to things:

```
People_with_a_wage = count(Wage, na.rm=T)
and
People_with_a_wage = n(Wage, na.rm=T)
```

Both give me an error that says there is a problem in group 1. If i remove the line or change the count to mean it works just fine.

How do i calculate the number of people with a wage?

Thank you

Comment: `sum(is.na(Wage))`?

Comment: Could you include some data: `dput(DF)` or `dput(head(DF, 20))` or some alternative to give a representative sample.

Comment: It's sum(!is.na(Wage)) But yes that is it. I knew it was something simple i was missing. Thank you :)